# How to make an interface more specific in Java?

Tags: java

I have a large system that uses two different sql databases.  I have very many places where both databases are included in a method.  For example:

```
public static void doSomething(Connection mySqlConn, Connection dbConn) {...}
```

Is there a simple (elegant) way to make the signature more specific.  For example:

```
public static void doSomething(MySqlConnection mySqlConn, DatabricksSqlConnection dbConn {...}
```

I tried to extend the Connection interface and then cast the connection to this interface but this gives a cannot cast exception (the widening of the interface is not allowed).

More specific interface

```
import java.sql.Connection;

public interface MySqlConnection extends Connection {

}
```

This throws an exception

```
public static MySqlConnection getMysqlConnection(String schema, String url, String uid, String pwd) {
    try {
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, uid, pwd);
        return (MySqlConnection) conn;
    } catch (Exception exp) {
        throw new RuntimeException(exp);
    }

}
```

Comment: You also have to provide an implementation of your interface. And then you have to return an instance of this one from your method.

Comment: Why?  The whole point of an interface is generalization, not specialization.  Is the problem that developers are swapping the two connections by accident?

Comment: Why not making the interface generic?

Comment: Why is your interface method `static`? Have you tried `interface DbInterface<C1 extends Connection, C2 extends Connection> { public void doSomething(C1 mySqlConn, C2 dbConn)`?

Comment: When you have more than one database, you could write an interface that does generic SQL CONNECT, SELECTS, INSERTS, UPDATES, and DELETES.  You would then write a concrete class for each database.  The user would pick a database, and you'd instantiate the interface with the concrete class for that database.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a direct answer to the question, but might solve your problem in a different way:

You can create a class that holds both `Connection`s as named members and then you can pass objects of this class instead of the two connections separately.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer!

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose: It *is* an answer.  Don't flag it just because it has a question mark in it.

Comment: I kind of like it.  Maybe something called ConnectionManager that has a getMySqlConn and getDbConn.  I could then get the individual connections at the very beginning of each existing method (requiring some modification to the body of the calling method).  Ideally I'd like to change the signature with zero modification to the bodies of the existing methods but I don't know if that is possible.  This comes very, very close.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are misusing the concepts of the DriverManager with this usecase.

The DriverManager is here to help you not introducing any Vendor Specific APIs when you are dealing with JDBC objects.

Your MySql JDBC driver already contains a dedicated Implemenation of the MySQL bundled (which an be instantiated by hand). There is already a `com.mysql.jdbc.Connection` Interface (which you could cast) and a `com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl` you could try to instantiate by yourself.

But this is **not** considered as good Practice at all.

Most probably a Factory or Holder object for you different Data Base Connections is the thing which could help you.